# Class method returning undefined on controller layer

Tags: node.js, express, class

I have a test where I need to build a REST API to create and edit products. I make it using node and express.

I'm using classes to try to apply SOLID principles, but when I create the Controller layer with class I have the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productsService')`

Even though it's referenced in the ProductsController constructor.

I have Model, Services, and Controller layers.

Model

```
class ProductsModel {
  constructor() {
    this.connection = connection;
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.connection.query('SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id');
  }
}

module.exports = new ProductsModel();
```

Services

```
class ProductsService {
  constructor() {
    this.model = ProductsModel;
  }

  async getAll() {
    const [products] = await this.model.getAll();
    return products;
  }
}

module.exports = new ProductsService();
```

Controller

```
class ProductsController {
  constructor() {
    this.productsService = ProductsService;
  }

  async getAll(_req, res) {
    const products = await this.productsService.getAll();
    return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json(products);
  }
}

module.exports = new ProductsController();
```

routes

```
const express = require('express');
const rescue = require('express-rescue');
const validadeProducts = require('../middlewares/validateProducts');
const ProductsController = require('../controllers/products');

const productsRouter = express.Router();

productsRouter
  .route('/products')
  .get(rescue(ProductsController.getAll))

module.exports = { productsRouter };
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

when i call the class method on rescue:

`.get(rescue(ProductsController.getAll))`

`this` is referenced to rescue instead of `ProductsController` class

to fix it i need to create the method as an anonymous function to keep `this` scope related to the `ProductsController` class:

```
getAll = async (_req, res) => {
    const products = await this.productsService.getAll();
    return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json(products);
  }
```